# How to take screenshots when user is logged off or locked using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, .net-4.5

My application takes screenshots and use the picture for more purposes
the program works automatically scheduled in windows task manager.

This working great when user is logged on but when user logged off or locked
the program takes black screenshots.

I understand that when the user logged off or locked there is no UI to taking screenshots from, but can i do something to do that task ?

is it possible... ? some ideas..?

the code i use for make the screenshot is:

```
using System.Drawing;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, options);
var arrScreen = driver.GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;

    using (var msScreen = new MemoryStream(arrScreen))
        {
            var bmpScreen = new Bitmap(msScreen);
            bmpScreen.Save(@"C:\screen.gif",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            ...
        }
```

what can i do for taking screenshots in that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) that is a headless browse but it'll take screenshot even when user logs off.

Best is to run your tests remotely on cloud using service like [Saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/), etc.